# jbuilder empty array removes key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

My Controller Returns the `@quotes`, which can be an empty array.

I then render the following view.

```
  json.set! :quotes do
    @quotes.each do |quote|
      json.set! quote.id do
        json.id       quote.id
        json.symbol   quote.symbol
        json.price    quote.price
        json.datetime quote.datetime
      end
    end
  end
```

This typically results in

```
"quotes": {
  "123": {
    "id": 123,
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "price": 100,
    "datetime": "2019-12-31T16:00:00.000Z"
},
```

However if @quotes is an empty array the response is

```
{}
```

When I want

```
{
  "quotes": {}
}
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal without an explicit check if the object is empty?

I **Do Not** want todo

```
if @quotes.empty?
  json.quotes({})
else
```

-- I am using Jbuilder 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [jb](https://github.com/amatsuda/jb) gem. It is simple to move from jbuilder to jb (i was doing it on production project). Jb few time faster than jbuilder and do not have ugly jbuilder syntax, it is just plain ruby. 
Your problem can be solved in jb

```
json = { quotes: {} }
@quotes.each do |quote|
  json[:quotes][quote.id] = {
    ...
  }
end

json
```